# How to get channel displayed on an Anytone 868UVE

Tags: anytone

How do we get the channel displayed on an Anytone 868UVE?

I'm probably missing something in the manual that is obvious elsewhere, but how do I get the display to show the **channel** I'm on and **not the zone**.

The channel is shown as a frequency, but the channel *name* is most important.  I already know what zone I'm on (and can check it quickly) but the all-important information (especially when changing channels) is what channel am I on?

This is especially when using DMR where the frequency is always the same! The Talkgroup is changing but it doesn't show up.

Comment: Can you [edit] this and tell us what research you have done. For example, does anything in the manual for this equipment related to "6.1" settings related to "CH Name" or "Frequency" have anything to do with what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes and No.  Due to the complexity of the setups, this type of radio really needs to be programmed via software and not the front panel.  If that option is set for Channel Name on the radio is it overwritten by the accompanying software to be for Frequency.  And there doesn't appear to be any option in the software to set that parameter.  So any changes/additions/updates to the programming (particularly updated repeaters) wipe out anything not in the software.

Comment: Comments are for asking for clarification, and aren't really part of the question. You can [edit] the question and provide new details there. Make sure you take the [tour] if you have not already.